# Add and remove cells on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView where I want the cells to animate adding and deleting the images when they are not in view.  Can someone point me toward some example code, I know its a quick question.

Basically the goal of mine is to have my collectionview display thumbnails and then when the user slows down their scrolling to animate the loading of photos in the cells and animate the removing of cells at the top of the frames view.

So my question areas are:
1. Detect speed of scrolling
2. Animate add and remove of images from cells
3. Only have cells in frame view shown
4. Something I may have missed.